# jquery Input remove first letter if it = x

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to create a function to remove the first character of the input box if it =P. We use a barcode scanner and it uses a prefix of P, when scanning part numbers I want to strip that out on the fly.

```
<input id="part" onKeyUp="fixP(this.value);"  size="20" type="text" name="part" style="text-transform: uppercase;"/>
<script>
function fixP() {
    $('#part').val($('#part').val().substr(1).replace(/P/,""));
}
</script>
```

This just results in continually removing anything I type in the input.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not hook into the on change event as well? http://jsfiddle.net/SKEwJ/2/

```
$("#part").change(function(){
    this.value = this.value.replace(/^[Pp]/,'');
});​
```

Comment: is this going to replace only if P is the first char?

Comment: +1 for the change event, although I would use more jQuery than regular javascript inside. and substring of course instead of replace.

Comment: @wirey Yes, that is the purpose of the RegEx `^` caret. It matches start of the string.

Comment: Why are you matching pipe as well? Do you mean `[Pp]` or `/^p/i`?

Comment: @Esailija Ah! You're right, too many languages mixed up in my head, fixed.

Comment: thanks Thez but this doesn't work, because part numbers can have P's in them in other spots, and I also have a hint function that fires so I can't leave PP in there till they tab out or they won't get any hints.

Comment: @user1499421 "I'm trying to create a function to remove the first character of the input box if it =P" Which is _exactly_ what this does. As for the hinting thing, then don't use it in the `change` hook, and use it like you were.

Comment: TheZ thank you this actually helped me with another field. I appreciate your time and knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you're selecting the substr index 1.

Try this:

```
<input id="part" onKeyUp="fixP(this.value);"  size="20" type="text" name="part" style="text-transform: uppercase;"/>
<script>
function fixP() {
    $('#part').val($('#part').val().replace(/^P/,""));
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Rick, but that would replace any P, I need to only replace first P.

Comment: @user1499421 The `^` only matches the first P.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#part").change(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().substring(1));
});
```

if second parameter is omitted in substring, it'll take the rest of the string as explained here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

And you can add a length check if you want to avoid unneccessary substrings later.

For example, the result will always be 13 chars long (without the "P" at the beginning):

```
$("#part").change(function(){
    if($(this).val().length==14) $(this).val($(this).val().substring(1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/DrWz6/1/

```
function fixP() {
    var value = $("#part").val();
    if(value.indexOf("p") == 0)
    {
        //alert("p");
        value = value.substring(1);
    }
    $("#part").val(value);
}
```

Comment: ur welcome, u should click on the UP arrow to the answer that u think was helpful to u

Answer (score 0):

```
function fixP() {
    var elm = document.getElementById('part');
    elm.value = elm.value.toUpperCase().indexOf('P') === 0 ? elm.value.substring(1) : elm.value;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ecBhf/1/)